# Problem in attaching event to canvas in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to attach an event to the fabricjs canvas and as far as I know, the best place to do so is useEffect with empty dependency [] just like componentDidMount in class component. When I attach there the function attached to the event returns null for the props. However, if I attache the event in the useEffect without any dependency, it works but whenever you drag, it renders several times and numbers grow after each drag. You can find the code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-wind-gfx2w

You can comment it out either in useEffect[] or useEffect without dependency to see the result after drag and drop items on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you bind a new `onDrop` event on each state update of the component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Attach event
    _foo.current.on("drop", handleDropFunc, false);
  });
```

So after dropping 5 items, `handleDropFunc` is attached 5 times to the fabric item.

The problem you are trying to tackle is a typical problem that is also described in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function). Try changing `Canvas.jsx` to:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

const Canvas = ({ activeControl }) => {
    const [controls, concatControls] = useState([]);
    const item = useRef(null);
    const _foo = useRef(0);

    const handleDropFunc = (e) => {
        addControl(e);
    };

    const addControl = (e) => {
        if (item.current && item.current.value) {
            var text = new fabric.IText(item.current.value, {
                fontFamily: 'arial black',
                fontSize: 16,
                width: 200,
                breakWords: true,
                left: e.e.offsetX - 80,
                top: e.e.offsetY - 20,
                myid: new Date()
                    .getTime()
                    .toString()
                    .substr(5),
                objecttype: 'text',
            });

            // concatControls(prev => {
            //   return [...prev, text];
            // });

            _foo.current.add(text).setActiveObject(text);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        _foo.current = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-element');
        _foo.current.on('drop', handleDropFunc, false);
    }, []);

    // On each update of `activeControl`, set the current item to
    // this current value so that it can be used in `addControl`
    useEffect(() => {
      item.current = activeControl;
    }, [activeControl]);

    return (
        <>
            <div style={{ border: '5px solid #eee' }}>
                <canvas id="canvas-element" width={600} height={400} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Canvas;
```

Or have a look here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-resonance-1kn78